# Is this Hilbert-related transform bounded?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, convolution

I have trouble deciding whether the transform $$T(f)(x)=\int_{\lvert x-t\rvert>1}\frac{f(t)}{\lvert x-t\rvert}\mathrm{d}t\text,\qquad f\in L^2(\mathbb{R})$$ is bounded. In fact, whether its values actually lie in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$. It seems related to the Hilbert transform. In other words: does putting modulus in the denominator of the Hilbert transform preserves boundedness, if one cuts out a neighbourhood of zero? Can anyone help?

Comment: Hint: consider Cauchy Schwarz inequality

Comment: Remember that is is $L^2$.

Comment: I am sorry, this was supposed to be a convolution of $f$ with the inverted modulus, similarily to the Hilbert transform. I have just edited the formula.

Comment: The more I look at the problem, the less clear it is how to use CS inequality here. Maybe it's trivial, but I just can't see it.